# Python OpenCV, Houghline detection around paper

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make an OMR sheet checker using python and OpenCV. I have an image consisting of 90 questions each with 4 choices.

[image: full image]
For easier evaluation, I am splitting the image into three images.One of which looks like this.

[image]

Now I need to form a bounding rectangle around it to carry on the further process from the tutorials [here](http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/03/tutorial-creating-multiple-choice.html/) and [here](http://pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/)

However, the code I am referencing is not giving proper results:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('face2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imshow('edges',edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

minLineLength = 30
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,15,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('hough',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

What I need is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is the paper always white? What about dirt etc.?

Comment: You didn't follow any of the tutorials at all. You just copied some code from somewhere applying Canny and then HoughLines. Just follow this step by step https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/ and you'll get the expected results.

Comment: @Timo Yes the paper is always white. I believe the Gaussian Blur will help in noise reduction.

Comment: @epinal Agreed that I am still a novice with cv2, the sheet shown in the tutorial and the sheet I have, vary in sizes. It leads to poor results in finding the contours.

Comment: Try to understand the steps and not miss any of them cause one thing leads to the other. Im pretty sure that if you put some effort and play with the arguments you can get it working as you wish. Welcome to CV world ;-)